# Script to Reboot Virgin SuperHub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, cron, perl

I'm currently trying to write a script that will reboot my Virgin SuperHub when set up as a cron job.

However, it keeps failing with the following error:
"There is no form with ID "VmRgRebootRestoreDevice" at /home/ricky/Downloads/Ubuntu/Scripts/SuperHubReboot.pl line 11."

This is the code within the script I have (using WWW:Mechanize on Ubuntu 16.04):

```
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 0);
#login
$url="http://@ARGV[0]";
$mech->get( $url );
$mech->form_name('VmLogin');
$mech->field("VmLoginUsername","@ARGV[1]");
$mech->field("VmLoginPassword","@ARGV[2]");
$mech->submit_form(); #get settings page and reboot $url = "http://@ARGV[0]/VmRgRebootRestoreDevice.asp";
$mech->get( $url );
$mech->form_id("VmRgRebootRestoreDevice");
$mech->field("VmDeviceRestore",'0');
$mech->field("VmDeviceReboot",'1');
$mech->submit_form(); exit;
```

I've checked the elements within the router portal and "VmRgRebootRestoreDevice" is the correct reference for the page it needs to go to reboot.

Does anyone have any experience of using a script to reboot their SuperHub? If so, how did you get it to work in Ubuntu / Linux?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Virgin SuperHub, but I have quite some experience with perl's WWW::Mechanize.

First thing I would do is checking the output of `$mech->dump_forms()`. `dump_forms` dumps information on all forms WWW::Mechanize find to STDOUT. This is something you probably would not let in the final code, but it is a great debugging aid.

Instead of adding it to your script's source, you could also use the perl debugger:

- Start the perl debugger with `perl -d /home/ricky/Downloads/Ubuntu/Scripts/SuperHubReboot.pl`
- Enter `c 11` to run the script until **before** executing line 11
- Then enter `$mech->dump_forms` (you could enter any perl statement in the perl debugger to execute it in the context of the current line)
- Check the output of `dump_forms`: Does the Virgin SuperHub's webinterface really use the 'name' attribute on the login page but an 'id' attribute afterwards?

You could also use `$mech->form_number($n)` to select the appropriate form (beware: form numbering in WWW::Mechanize starts at 1!).

Comment: Where does the $mech->dump_forms() output to? Sorry, I've only just started using WWW::Mechanize so not completely familiar with it yet.